# Why take just one? Linq to XML C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I can't figure out why my code just taking the first  tag and not the rest.

```
var xml = XDocument.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Themes.xml"));

var q = from f in xml.Descendants("themes")
        select new ThemesItem
        {
            Name = f.Element("theme").Element("name").Value,
            Description = f.Element("theme").Element("description").Value,
            Author = f.Element("theme").Element("author").Value,
        };

return q.ToList();
```

ThemeItem is just a get set with public string
When i write out this data i use a repeater
Thanks for help :)

Comment: Can you provide some sample XML?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is because the Descendants extension method takes all decendants of the xml node, that is named "themes". Since your themes node is the container for the individual theme tags, there is only one, and when you take .Element on that, you get the first occurence.

This code should work:

```
var q = from f in xml.Descendants("theme")
        select new ThemesItem
        {
            Name = f.Element("name").Value,
            Description = f.Element("description").Value,
            Author = f.Element("author").Value,
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<themes>
  <theme>
    <name>Standard</name>
    <description>standard theme</description>
    <author>User 1</author>
    <folder>standard</folder>
  </theme>
  <theme>
    <name>Standard</name>
    <description>standard theme</description>
    <author>User 2</author>
    <folder>standard</folder>
  </theme>
</themes>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using XElement.Load() instead of XDocument.Load()

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675196.aspx